# Docker containers running and accessible from inside the vm but cant access them from browser

Tags: docker, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I am using docker to run instances of elasticsearch ,kibana and mysql with docker compose

this is the output of `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                 NAMES
bf9204351a5a   docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.11.0                 "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   44 seconds ago   Up 43 seconds   0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp, :::5601->5601/tcp             kb-container
f20bfdf11e33   docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.0   "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   45 seconds ago   Up 43 seconds   0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp, :::9200->9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   es-container
0c0add6cd7fe   mysql:5.6.27                                           "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   21 minutes ago   Up 21 minutes   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp             mysql
```

and when I do `curl http://127.0.0.1:9200` it gives me output as well

But when I access it from my browser site not reached error

I have checked for firewalls

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

And my port 80 nginx (not on docker container) is running perfectly from browser

These are my docker-compose files

elastic and kibana

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: es-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.0
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
    networks:
      - es-net
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  kibana:
    container_name: kb-container
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.11.0
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://es-container:9200
    networks:
      - es-net
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
networks:
  es-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem (i.e. used your compose file launched the services and reached both of them from my broswer). Are you on windows or masOS? These OS usually run the docker daemon inside a dedicated VM. If your browser runs on your local OS environment, you need to give the ip of the given vm instead of localhost.

Comment: the problem was snap version of docker compose - i installed from official repo and it worked

Comment: Reference -https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423293/ubuntu-22-04-docker-containers-not-accessible-from-outside